# Change storage path in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible to change to the storage path? I want it to be outside of the repository in our production environment, for deployments to work properly.

The default path is `app/storage/`. We are using 4.1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can define it in `bootstrap/paths.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Storage Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The storage path is used by Laravel to store cached Blade views, logs
| and other pieces of information. You may modify the path here when
| you want to change the location of this directory for your apps.
|
*/

'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

Don't forget to set the required read/write permissions for the new directory.

Comment: Such file does not seem to exist anymore

Comment: @reallynice correct, it's no longer present since Laravel 5.x. Now it needs to be done using `$app->useStoragePath($storage);`

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8, it can be set in `bootstrap/app.php` as follows:

```
$app->instance('path.storage', '/tmp/laravel_storage');
```

Based on https://www.amezmo.com/blog/how-to-change-the-default-storage-path-in-laravel/, but there they set it in the `register()` method of the `AppServiceProvider`, which appears to be too late. Setting it in `bootstrap/app.php`, like in jehon's answer, seems to work, though.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.0, you can do that in bootstrap\app.php

```
$app->useStoragePath("/tmp/laravel_storage/");
```

Hope this will help someone...

Edit:
In Laravel 5.1, this is not enough anymore...

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 7 through 10, and likely newer versions, too, you can change the config file at `app/filesystems.php`.

I think the cleanest solution would be to add a disk with a different root, for example

```php
'my_custom_path' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('path/from/storage/folder'),
],
```

In this example, `'driver' => 'local'` tells the disk is in your project's folder (rather than via FTP, DAV, S3, etc.). and `'root' => ...` sets the actual file path. This can be anything, but it's good practice to leave this under the `/storage` folder in your project, not in any other folder.

After this, you can use code like this to write or retrieve files:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// Writing "Hello world!" in "file.txt" in your new, custom disk.
Storage::disk('my_custom_path')->put('file.txt', 'Hello world!');

// Retrieving the contents of file.txt in your disk as plain-text.
Storage::disk('my_custom_path')->get('file.txt');
```

Or you can go to your .env file and change `FILESYSTEM_DISK=local` to `FILESYSTEM_DISK=my_custom_path`. If you do this, your new custom disk is set as default and you never need to specify `disk('my_custom_path')` when using storage, anymore!